# Nativescript bluetooth and bluetooth v5.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I'm currently looking into an issue where my companys app have some trouble establishing searches and connection to a cadence BLE peripheral.

We're developing using nativescript@6.1.2 {N}6 and for the past long while we've used the nativescript-bluetooth@1.3.1 plugin with no issue. It's been used primarily on tablets with bluetooth 4.x.
Problem started when we tried our app on Samsung Galaxy tab A7 with bluetooth v5.0. The app wouldn't start a search or connect with the usual peripheral [Wahoo cadence sensor](https://eu.wahoofitness.com/devices/bike-sensors/wahoo-rpm-cadence-sensor).

What I can do is see the Wahoo sensor in the Android Bluetooth Manager as well as nRF connect and Wahoo's Fitness app. But using the usual plugin doesn't seem to be able to do anything.
I'm still fairly new to the BLE programming game, so if anybody have any advice as to why the Samsung Galaxy tab A7 with bluetooth 5.0 won't connect, I'd be happy to receive some.

Comment: At the end i ended up upgrading to NS7 (which we were already in progress of) which fixed the issue. Would still love to know if anybody have know whether it's available or not.

Answer (score 0):

So nativescript-bluetooth 1.3.1 is no longer valid in Android versions 10+. I have to migrate my app to nativescript 7 as well. I'm having trouble with migrating, and if you have any suggestions for some of my questions, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have a source or can you guide me as to where i can see that 1.3.1 is incompatible with Android 10+? 
I'll gladly assist with the migration in any way possible. Throw me a PM and we'll see if I can be of help.

Comment: According to the nativescript community slack and two developers that work on the bluetooth android side, "Android changed permissions required for BLE scanning in Android 10, and nativescript-bluetooth@1.3 wouldn’t have those adaptations." I'm using 1.3 on my iOS side and it works fine, but has stopped working for Android devices 10+ (after testing it myself as well).

Comment: How do I send a PM?

Comment: Ahhh apparently you can't - my bad. Lets chat over reddit. I'm named Handicrab and have made an issue post there as well. https://www.reddit.com/r/nativescript/comments/k3xcue/question_regarding_bluetooth_50/

Comment: Sent you a message through reddit. I'm jrocker3